# How to disable an input field using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

I'm starting with Javascript, I wrote this function:

```
function disableField() {
  if( document.getElementById("valorFinal").length > 0 ) ) {
    document.getElementById("cantidadCopias").disabled = true; 
  }
}
```

Which disables the second field named cantidadCopias if the first one is filled.

```
<label> <span>Valor final:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="valorFinal" id="valorFinal" onkeydown="disableField()"/>
</label>
<label> <span>Cantidad de Copias:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="cantidadCopias" id="cantidadCopias"/>
</label>
```

But it's not disabling the second field when the first one is filled.

Comment: Someone has a spelling problem document.getElementById("valorFinal").lenght <-- length

Comment: You have forgot to tell us where your problem is. What is aour question?

Comment: Sorry I've edited the question.

Comment: you should hook onkeyup instead of onkeydown. besides you should enable the second input again when the first reaches a length of 0 again. just look at my answer for an example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Did you look at the console?

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
- Uncaught ReferenceError: disableField is not defined

First time you had a spelling error, now your code has an extra `)`

```
function disableField() {
  if( document.getElementById("valorFinal").length > 0 ) ) {  <-- extra )
    document.getElementById("cantidadCopias").disabled = true; 
  }
}​
```

Now the next issue is you are not looking at the length of the value.

```
if( document.getElementById("valorFinal").length > 0 )  <-- you are looking at the length of the HTML DOM Node.
```

So the code should look like

```
function disableField() {
  if( document.getElementById("valorFinal").value.length > 0 ) { 
    document.getElementById("cantidadCopias").disabled = true; 
  }
}​
```

but now how it is written, once it is disabled, it will not be re-enabled.

```
function disableField() {
    var isDisabled = document.getElementById("valorFinal").value.length > 0; 
    document.getElementById("cantidadCopias").disabled = isDisabled;
}​
```

Comment: i like how you copyed the last part. /irony

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky I did not copy anything of yours. Flatter yourself thinking that I did.

Answer (score 2):

It is best if you use `onkeyup()` instead of `onkeydown()`. The problem is the value of the input is not updated on keydown event.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LVg7/)

```
<label> 
  <span>Valor final:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="valorFinal" id="valorFinal" onkeyup="disableField(this.value)"/>
 </label>
<label> 
  <span>Cantidad de Copias:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="cantidadCopias" id="cantidadCopias"/>
</label>
```

javascript

```
function disableField(val) {
    var cantidadCopias = document.getElementById("cantidadCopias");
    cantidadCopias.disabled = ( val.length > 0  );
}
```

Comment: console.log is not avilable in browsers without an attached debugger. (firefox or IE without an open dev console as example) besides that your whole answer has already been posted.

Comment: Commented out the `console.log()` it is more cleaner than the others perhaps.:)

Comment: @Bob you don't need the ternary operation because `val.length > 0` by itself is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

the javascript:

```
var disableField = function () {
  var state = document.getElementById("valorFinal").value.length > 0;
  document.getElementById("cantidadCopias").disabled = state;
}​;​
```

the html:

```
<label> <span>Valor final:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="valorFinal" id="valorFinal" onkeyup="disableField()"/>
</label>
<label> <span>Cantidad de Copias:</span>
  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="cantidadCopias" id="cantidadCopias"/>
</label>​
```

you should also enable it again when the input length is 0 again.

besides that you should hook onkeyup and not onkeydown.

you can try it here: [jsfiddle.net/DBJfN/](http://jsfiddle.net/DBJfN/)

Comment: Thanks, the onkeyup thing solved the problem I had with field not enabling until pressing Del key again (when it was empty).

Comment: no problem. onblur could also be of interest for you in case someone clicks somewhere while holding a key down (before onkeyup got fired)