# Add parameter disabled to textarea by JS

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

How I can add parameter disabled in textarea tag (HTML) by JavaScript ?
When in textarea is more than 300 characters then I want to disabled textarea

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea id="sms"></textarea>
        <button type="button">Wyślij</button>

        <div class="licznik"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var licznik = document.querySelector(".licznik");
        var btn = document.querySelector("button");
        var textarea = document.getElementById("sms");

        let wynik = textarea.addEventListener("keyup", function licz (){
           let polska = textarea.value.length;
            licznik.innerHTML = polska;
            if(polska >=300){
                licznik.innerHTML ="Za dużo znaków";
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable an input field using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896698/how-to-disable-an-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable textarea with this code:

```
textarea.disabled = true;
```

And return it to default state:

```
textarea.disabled = false;
```